# Om Next tutorial: Components Identity Normalization -- om/db->tree usage

Tags: clojurescript, om

The [Components, Identity & Normalization](https://github.com/omcljs/om/wiki/Components%2C-Identity-%26-Normalization) Om Next tutorial says to evaluate some `om.next/db->tree` calls at the REPL to understand normalization.

The tutorial has two components, Person and RootView.  Person implements `om/Ident`. Calling `(om/tree->db RootView init-data true)` normalizes the data with the `:person/by-name` table, as expected.

I tried doing the same thing with Person instead: `(om/tree->db Person init-data true)` but the normalization table wasn't in the result.

Can you help me understand how `tree->db` uses the Person ident with the RootView, but not with the Person?

Comment: You may wana add a `clojurescript` tag to this stackoverflow question. Not many check out `om`. I only got here thru slack

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend doing the interactive tutorial (which is a project you can check out and interactively edit):

http://www.github.com/awkay/om-tutorial

This allows you to interactively play with queries and database formats which will significantly help your understanding.

UPDATE: I've long since created a project called Fulcro. Version 1 stacks on top of Om Next to make things *very* much simpler, and Version 2 (December 1, 2017) is a standalone library (no longer using Om Next) that has a lot of API compatibility, but improved usability, documentation, and more. https://fulcrologic.github.io/fulcro/

Comment: Thanks!  I've been working through the tutorials at https://github.com/omcljs/om/wiki#om-next and relying heavily on the repl, cljs.repl/doc, and cljs.repl/source.  I've heard good things about your tutorial and planned to check it out.

Comment: I actually came here through your tutorial (from https://github.com/awkay/om-tutorial/blob/master/src/tutorial/om_tutorial/C_App_Database_Exercises.cljs).